# TypeScript: Object Duplication impact on performance

Tags: performance, node.js, typescript, memory-optimization

For a library I am working on, I have created a class `WatchableCollection` which will monitor an endpoint of an API for updates and issue events (`WatchableCollection` extends `EventEmitter`). The constructor of `WatchableCollection` takes an initial set of values to store and an async function to check for new endpoints.

Users of `WatchableCollection` can enable polling the check function for new updates using the `.watch()` method, and stop polling using the `.unwatch()` method.

Where my concern rests is in the method I have added recently, `.filter()` which will return a new `WatchableCollection` with only items that meet the passed predicate function. **Additionally, it updates the check function of this new WatchableCollection to only issue events on new/updated items that fit this predicate**. This is where I have concerns for extra network requests and/or memory allocation.

```
// WatchableCollection.ts

/**
   * Returns a new WatchableCollection of the items which pass the filter.
   * Note this collection is watchable, and watch events will only be triggered for items that fit the filter function.
   *
   * @example
   * const event = await robotevents.events.get(sku);
   * const skills = (await event.skills()).filter(run => run.score > 30);
   *
   * skills.watch();
   * skills.on("add", run => console.log("New run over 30pts", run));
   *
   * @param predicate
   */
  filter(
    predicate: (
      item: T,
      id: I,
      collection: WatchableCollection<T, I>
    ) => boolean
  ): WatchableCollection<T, I> {
    const inital: [I, T][] = [];

    for (const [id, item] of this.contents) {
      if (predicate(item, id, this)) {
        inital.push([id, item]);
      }
    }

    // Filtered check
    const check: CheckFunction<T, I> = (collection) =>
      Promise.resolve(this.check(this)).then((runs) =>
        runs.filter((run) => predicate(run, run.id, collection))
      );

    return new WatchableCollection(inital, check);
  }
```

Here is the whole `WatchableCollection.ts` file, and you can view the rest of the codebase in context on [GitHub](https://github.com/MayorMonty/robotevents);

```
/**
 * Creates a watchable collection,
 * basically an array of contents that can be passed .watch()
 * to watch for updates
 *
 * const teams = await event.teams()
 */

import { EventEmitter } from "events";

interface WatchableCollectionEvents<T> {
  add: (item: T) => void;
  remove: (item: T) => void;
  update: (current: T, old: T) => void;
}

export default interface WatchableCollection<T> {
  on<U extends keyof WatchableCollectionEvents<T>>(
    event: U,
    listener: WatchableCollectionEvents<T>[U]
  ): this;
  once<U extends keyof WatchableCollectionEvents<T>>(
    event: U,
    listener: WatchableCollectionEvents<T>[U]
  ): this;
  off<U extends keyof WatchableCollectionEvents<T>>(
    event: U,
    listener: WatchableCollectionEvents<T>[U]
  ): this;
}

type CheckFunction<T extends { id: I }, I> = (
  self: WatchableCollection<T, I>
) => Promise<T[]> | T[];

export default class WatchableCollection<T extends { id: I }, I = number>
  extends EventEmitter
  implements Map<I, T> {
  // Holds all of contents of the collection
  private contents: Map<I, T> = new Map<I, T>();

  // Polling config
  private check: CheckFunction<T, I>;
  private interval: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
  private frequency: number = 30 * 1000;
  polling = false;

  constructor(inital: [I, T][], check: CheckFunction<T, I>) {
    super();

    this.contents = new Map(inital);
    this.check = check;
  }

  // Map methods

  clear() {
    this.contents.clear();
  }

  delete(id: I) {
    if (!this.contents.has(id)) {
      throw new Error(
        `WatchableCollection does not contain item with id ${id}`
      );
    }

    this.emit("remove", this.contents.get(id) as T);
    return this.contents.delete(id);
  }

  get(id: I) {
    return this.contents.get(id);
  }

  has(id: I) {
    return this.contents.has(id);
  }

  set(id: I, value: T) {
    if (this.contents.has(id)) {
      this.emit("update", value, this.contents.get(id) as T);
    } else {
      this.emit("add", value);
    }

    this.contents.set(id, value);
    return this;
  }

  get size() {
    return this.contents.size;
  }

  forEach(callback: (value: T, key: I, map: Map<I, T>) => void) {
    this.contents.forEach(callback);
  }

  keys() {
    return this.contents.keys();
  }
  values() {
    return this.contents.values();
  }
  entries() {
    return this.contents.entries();
  }

  [Symbol.iterator] = this.entries;
  [Symbol.toStringTag] = "WatchableCollection";

  // Other utility methods
  array(): T[] {
    return [...this.contents.values()];
  }

  idArray(): I[] {
    return [...this.contents.keys()];
  }

  /**
   * Returns a new WatchableCollection of the items which pass the filter.
   * Note this collection is watchable, and watch events will only be triggered for items that fit the filter function.
   *
   * @example
   * const event = await robotevents.events.get(sku);
   * const skills = (await event.skills()).filter(run => run.score > 30);
   *
   * skills.watch();
   * skills.on("add", run => console.log("New run over 30pts", run));
   *
   * @param predicate
   */
  filter(
    predicate: (
      item: T,
      id: I,
      collection: WatchableCollection<T, I>
    ) => boolean
  ): WatchableCollection<T, I> {
    const inital: [I, T][] = [];

    for (const [id, item] of this.contents) {
      if (predicate(item, id, this)) {
        inital.push([id, item]);
      }
    }

    // Filtered check
    const check: CheckFunction<T, I> = (collection) =>
      Promise.resolve(this.check(this)).then((runs) =>
        runs.filter((run) => predicate(run, run.id, collection))
      );

    return new WatchableCollection(inital, check);
  }

  /**
   * Looks for an item in the collection
   * @param predicate
   */
  find(
    predicate: (
      item: T,
      id: I,
      collection: WatchableCollection<T, I>
    ) => boolean
  ): T | undefined {
    for (const [id, item] of this.contents) {
      if (predicate(item, id, this)) {
        return item;
      }
    }

    return undefined;
  }

  /**
   * Checks if some of the elements in the collection pass the criterion
   * @param predicate
   */
  some(
    predicate: (
      item: T,
      id: I,
      collection: WatchableCollection<T, I>
    ) => boolean
  ) {
    for (const [id, item] of this.contents) {
      if (predicate(item, id, this)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Checks if every singe one of the elements in the collection pass the criterion
   * @param predicate
   */
  every(
    predicate: (
      item: T,
      id: I,
      collection: WatchableCollection<T, I>
    ) => boolean
  ) {
    for (const [id, item] of this.contents) {
      if (!predicate(item, id, this)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  // Watching
  watch(frequency?: number) {
    this.polling = true;
    if (frequency) {
      this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    this.interval = setInterval(async () => {
      const current = new Map(makeMappable<T, I>(await this.check(this)));

      // Check for new and updated items
      for (const [id, value] of current) {
        if (!this.contents.has(id)) {
          this.set(id, value);
          continue;
        }

        const old = this.contents.get(id) as T;

        if (!eq(value, old)) {
          this.set(id, value);
        }
      }

      // Check for removed values
      for (const [id, value] of this.contents) {
        if (current.has(id)) continue;

        this.delete(id);
      }
    }, this.frequency);
  }

  unwatch() {
    if (!this.polling || !this.interval) {
      return;
    }

    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new watchable collection from a check function
   * @param check
   */
  static async create<T extends { id: number }>(
    check: () => Promise<T[]> | T[]
  ) {
    const inital = makeMappable(await check());
    return new WatchableCollection(inital, check);
  }
}

function makeMappable<T extends { id: I }, I = number>(values: T[]): [I, T][] {
  return Object.entries(values).map(([i, value]) => [value.id, value]);
}

function eq(a: object, b: object): boolean {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a)) {
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(key)) return false;
    const compare = (b as any)[key];

    switch (typeof compare) {
      case "object": {
        return eq(value, compare);
      }

      default: {
        if (value !== compare) return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

My concerns are twofold:

- There is a high possibility the original `WatchableCollection` will go out of scope of the user, however it won't be able to GC'd because the new `WatchableCollection` is referencing the old collection's check function. The contents of the collection can be fairly large, so this can lead to memory leaks.
- Even though polling needs to be activated by the user via `.watch()`, there is still a possibility that polling is enabled on the old collection via `.watch()`, and if it went out of scope, the user would have no ability to disable watching. Caching might help mitigate the problems of this, but there is still going to be overhead.

Is there a way I can refactor `.filter` to ensure the old `WatchableCollection` has all references removed, allowing it to be Garbage Collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're right to be concerned.

Your example is essentially this

```
function wrapCheck(check) {
      return {
            check,
            largeArr: Array(1000000)
                  .fill(0)
                  .map((_, i) => i),
            makeNew: function (pred) {
                  return wrapCheck(() => check(this).filter(pred));
            }
      };
}

const check = (o) => o.largeArr.slice(0, 10);

let s = wrapCheck(check);
while (true) {
      s = s.makeNew((x) => x % 2 === 0);
}
```

Which yes is a memory leak (takes about 20 secs to run out of memory for me).

I'll confess I haven't fully appreciated your code, but what prevents you from making a new WatchableCollection with just initial, and adding the check on afterwards, now using the reference to your newly made object?

Comment: The main problem lies in the new Collections check function to be reliant on filtering the old function. Because check is making a request against the same endpoint, it may be possible to refactor check to be copied across into the new collection instead. 

The problem lies in the fact the collection check function is reliant on the previous collection. It may be possible to encode check in such a way that check can be copied (as all my check functions right now are just using the same request function).

Thanks!